# Can you write a type guard that can identify more than one type?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking into [type narrowing in TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). They provide this example to check one type. It compiles to a function returning a bool.

```
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}
```

What I would like though is a function that can take multiple types and spits out the type. Something like this:

```
const isAnimalType = (
  animal: Cat | Dog | Bird | Fish
): animal is Cat | Dog | Bird | Fish =>
  {
    switch (true) {
      case animal instanceof Cat:
        return is Cat;
      case animal instanceof Dog:
        return is Dog;
      ...
  }
```

How would one do such a thing in TS?

Comment: That's a type guard of _one type_, and that type is the union `Cat | Dog | Bird | Fish`. It's not really clear how you're intending to use this.

Comment: TypeScript is a language that's statically-compiled before runtime. Any runtime logic is happening after all the types are erased and won't have any influence on the compiler.

Comment: The only way this would work is if user-defined type guard functions could return non-`boolean` values, which is requested in [ms/TS#46650](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46650).  Without that feature, the only return values from `isAnimalType()` would be `true` or `false`, and that only lets you split `Cat | Dog | Bird | Fish` in two, not in four.  So this is a no-go for now unless I am misunderstanding what you want.  Does that fully address your question?  If so I could write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz yes, that is my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this would work is if `isAnimalType()` could return four different values.  After all, you'd need to actually examine the return value and do something specific to `Cat` or `Dog` or `Bird` or `Fish` with it.  So, maybe it returns one of the four strings `"cat"` or `"dog"` or `"bird"` or `"fish"`.  Then you could maybe use it like this:

```
// this doesn't work, sorry
if (isAnimalType(animal) === "cat" /* or some value */) {
    animal.meow();
}
```

where `isAnimalType(animal) === "cat"` would automatically narrow `animal` to type `Cat`, so `animal.meow()` would type-check.  No matter what, you'd need four different values to come out of `isAnimalType()`.

---

But [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) *must* return `boolean` values, and there are only two of those: `true` and `false`.  So it's just not possible in TypeScript as of now.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#46650](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46650) asking for type guard functions that return non-`boolean` values, and if this were implemented (although there's no indication that this will happen) then *maybe* you'd have some way to implement this.  But for now it is not possible.

Two is less than four.

---

But: there's not a *lot* of difference between `if (isAnimalType(animal) === "cat")` and `if (isAnimalType(animal, "cat"))`.  The former doesn't work with a `boolean` return type, but the latter does.  And so, if you want, you could do something like this:

```
interface AnimalMap {
    cat: Cat,
    dog: Dog,
    bird: Bird,
    fish: Fish
}
const isAnimalType = <K extends keyof AnimalMap>(
    animal: AnimalMap[keyof AnimalMap],
    animalType: K
): animal is AnimalMap[K] => {
    return animal instanceof (
        { cat: Cat, dog: Dog, bird: Bird, fish: Fish }
    )[animalType];
}
```

Which now works as desired:

```
if (isAnimalType(animal, "cat")) {
    animal.meow(); // okay
}
```

So that might be a workaround, depending on your use case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYBdoG9oFsCmB7A7gCgEoVoBfUgKFEhgBEsBzYnLLAM0OLJMvCmgCEAlgCcAJsQQ4MGBB1Rce1aADFBEABbF6IAK4AjOaQrlBAOwQZhrMMAzQAgqcFowIALJgADinLQ-0YEQALjhEABpff1EGELp6CP9oPRFREKExBP9WNXUQ1Q1ybmAsUwgkNUdnVwAVAE9POwBeaAAeAGloDAAPC1NRGABrDFq2BycXdy8APjxIvzBx1xDKiY9PAG0hkdYxqsnPAF1M+cWQOoaQtvICEIW96DVd1a91toPoRqmfROEZHWFTNA7hMHqUEAtbKNZolEqhAggQvAEGFoNF6LEGCjkmI0ikUdkNHkchREgR1sCavUMAcANyFcjkVg6UzABCCEqorAAZQQOlY7ApIERiGgAB9oHExQIUlL8uoiMg5g8dngKqdzhg8IKUQAieE6ggKpWJQUAOkwuEIdMS3BIQA)